# Found string with regex in AWK or SED

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I want to find for example the following string 9Stest1.test2D9 in File. Then i want to cut the first 2 charechter and last 2 charechter and finally print the text befor and after . in two seperate Line.

Example Text :

```
7U8vTest(#G-HLjYM6QqJj1j"7MFx$^Qd
.f@alU|A#Z<inCWV6a=L?o`A5vIod"%Mm+YW1RM@,L;aN
r^n<&)}[??!VcVIV**9Stest1.test2D9**94EN~yK,$lU=9?UT.[
e`)G:FS.nGz%?@~k!20aLJ^PU-[@}0W\ !8x
cujOmEK"1;!cI134lu%0-A +/t!VIf?8uT`!
aC1QAQY>4RE$46iVjAE^eo5yR|
1?/T?<H5,%G~[|9I/c&8MY$O]%,UYQe{!{Bm[rRC[
aHC`<m?BUau@N_O>Yct.MXo[>r5^uV&26@MkYB'Kiu\Y
K(*}ldO:ZQnI8t989fi+
```

Output should be so :

```
test1
test2
```

I have tried with following code `grep "[0-9][a-zA-Z]\+\.[a-zA-Z]\+[0-9]"` to find the string.Now i can cut the firs two line with `cut command` but last two line?
I think with `AWK` can i solve my problem easily but i dont know how.
Thanks

Comment: How do you like to search for your string, just search for it direct or any text between `**` etc???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see this line if it helps:

```
kent$  grep -Po '(?<=9S).*?(?=D9)' file
test1.test2
```

or more dynamic, this works for your example:

```
kent$  grep -Po '(?<=\d[a-zA-Z]).*\..*(?=[a-zA-Z]\d)' file
test1.test2
```

EDIT

as @devnull suggested, to get the desired output, you could

```
grep -Po '(?<=\d[a-zA-Z]).*\..*(?=[a-zA-Z]\d)' file|tr '.' '\n'
```

Comment: Maybe pipe the output to `tr '.' '\n'` to get the result in the _desired format_?

Comment: @devnull thx, updated the answer, didn't see OP added the output part in question.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how and what to search for.  Like text between `**`

```
awk -F"**"  '{a=substr($2,3,length($2)-4)} a {print a}'
test1.test2
dO:ZQnI8t989f
```