# AWK regex to find String with pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a File that contain too many charechter and symbols. I want to find an exact string and then cut it and give it to two variables. I have write it with `grep` but i want to write it in `**AWK**` or `SED`.

Here is my example file :

```
.f@alU|A#Z<inCWV6a=L?o`A5vIod"%Mm+YW1RM@,L;aN
r^n<&)}[??!VcVIV**2zTest1.Test2n9**94EN~yK,$lU=9?UT.[
e`)G:FS.nGz%?@~k!20aLJ^PU-[@}0W\ !8x
cujOmEK"1;!cI134lu%0-A +/t!VIf?8uT`!
aC1QAQY>4RE$46iVjAE^eo5yR|
1?/T?<H5,%G~[|9I/c&8MY$O]%,UYQe{!{Bm[rRC[
aHC`<m?BUau@N_O>Yct.MXo[>r5^uV&26@MkYB'Kiu\Y
K(*}ldO:ZQnI8t989fi+
CrvEwmTQ80k3==,a'Jj9907+}NNy=0Op
"nzb.j-.i%z5`U*8]~@64sF'r;\x\;ylr_;q5F` A!~p*
```

first i want to find **2zTest1.Test2n9** then cut the first 2 and last two charechter and finally get Two Words without dot(.). First word will i send to one variable and second one two another Variable.

Note : I want to find **2zTest1.Test2n9** and then i want to cut it.

output :

```
variable 1 = test1
variable 2 = test2
```

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655060/found-string-with-regex-in-awk-or-sed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed` its:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(2z\(\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\)n9\).*/variable 1 = \L\3\nvariable 2 = \L\4/p'  your.file
```

Output:

```
variable 1 = test1
variable 2 = test2
```

Comment: Thanks. I dont want to give in my sed command **2z** and **n9**. Can i use `regex` for example `[0-9][a-z]` instead of the 2z and n9.

Comment: [0-9][a-z] as start delimiter will only work if it is sure the that the varname is uppercased. However [a-z][0-9] will never work as the ending delimiter because the var name itself contains [a-z]

Comment: it is not  always `2z` and `n9` for example somthimes is `2X` and `T9` or `2g` and `M9`. 2 and 9 are permanent but before and after these Numbers are variable.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk:

```
read var1 var2 < <(
    gawk 'match($0, /2[[:alpha:]]([^.]+)\.(.*)[[:alpha:]]9/, m) {
        print m[1], m[2]
    }' file
)
echo "var1=$var1"
echo "var2=$var2"
```

```
var1=Test1
var2=Test2
```

I read your comments to hek2mgl's answer -- those requirement need to be in the question itself.